# WCF Nhibernate Service with Integrated Security=True error

Tags: wcf, security, nhibernate, service, integrated

I am working on a WCF Service(implemented with Fluent NH), and it is hosted as a Windows Service.

I am using a console application to test calling service methods.

Now, when I set connection string in hibernate.cfg.xml as

```
<property name="connection.connection_string">Server=dev;Initial Catalog=DBTest;Integrated Security=True;</property>
```

It throws the error:
***SqlException:* *Login failed for user***

But if I change connection string to:

```
<property name="connection.connection_string">Server=dev;Initial Catalog=DBTest;User Id=twr;Password=manager1;</property>
```

It successfully calls the service methods.

While all WCF Service Library, Hosting Windows Service and Console Application sits on my local machine only,

Can anyone please help me in understanding why it doesn't work with Integrated Security=true?

Thank you!

Comment: Under what account does your Windows Service that hosts your WCF run? That's the user that tries to connect to SQL Server - that user might not be permitted to do so.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Well, I am not sure about 'what account'. But I have been doing with Integrated Security= true for all other applications. Even if I unit test the wcf serice method (not calling through windows service), it works fine with Integrated Security. This error only comes up when I call it through Windows Service in test console application.

Comment: Yes, of course - if you run the WCF service outside the Windows service, it's run under your own user - and I assume you have the necessary permissions and all. But when you run something inside a Windows service, you have to define on the Windows service which account that serviec is going to be run under - if that account doesn't have enough privileges, esp. if it doesn't have a SQL Server account, it won't be able to log in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integrated Security = true means that this application will attempt to authenticate itself using "Windows Authentication" mode on the SQL Server you're connecting to. The service is running under a particular user account - it will use that user's account permissions to login to SQL.

If your SQL Server instance does not permit the user account of that Windows Service to login, you'll get that error. It's quite likely that the user the service runs as in your unit test is different than the test console application.

Try this - run your test console application and bring up Task Manager. Under the processes tab, look at the process associated with your service and the username it is running under. Run your unit test framework and note the username as well - they're probably different.

Go to SQL Server Management Studio and check to see under Security -> Logins whether the account that the service runs as (the one you found by using Task Manager) is listed. If not, add it and grant it permissions.

Comment: My point exactly - thanks for wording it more precisely, clearly and extensively! ;-)

Comment: Thank you marc and phyllis for reply.
Yes, you are right they are being run as different user when I checked user account in task manager. For unit test, it is showing my name. Whereas for Windows Service, it was showing as SYSTEM. I changed the Windows Service LogOn as property to myself, and it is working fine :-). Thanks once again.